# Getting "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment" when running my code

Tags: python

I've written a small code to check if my word is Palindrome or not:

```
def PalorNot():
  a =input("Enter your word here: ")
  for n in range(0,n+1,1):
    if (a[0]==a[-(n+1)]):
      print("Your word is a Palindrome")
      break
    else:
      print("Your word is not a Palindrome")

PalorNot()
```

However, I'm getting this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment" when running my code.

Strange part is, if I comment out def PalorNot(): and it's call, code works flawless.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm trying to learn Python.

Comment: What do you expect `range(0,n+1,1)` to return when `n` is not defined yet? Besides your code doesn't properly check for a palindrome. It reaches a verdict after only checking the first character.

Comment: @Selcuk Not sure, what you mean. As per my understanding, n will be running from this range(0,n+1,1) as it used to do in the example of printing 1 to 10:

for n in range(0, 11, 1):
print(n)



If I'm mistaken, can you please correct my actual code and explain what went wrong?

Comment: True, but what is the value of `n` in `range(0,n+1,1)`?

Comment: @Selcuk n is actually referring to the index of the string which I'm trying move from index 0 to (n+1). Seems I'm missing a basic thing. If you can please explain me with an example that would be great!

Comment: @Selcuk I guess, I now know what the issue was(atleast have a hint):

if I write      for i in range(0,n+1,1)    that would work and is correct?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be correct because there is no `n`. I don't know how else to explain this but `range(0,n+1,1)` doesn't mean anything if you don't know what `n` is. In your other example (`range(0, 11, 1)`) it's a known number (`11`).

Comment: Then I'm wondering how can I get from 0th index to last index in the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in this line:

```
for n in range(0,n+1,1):
```

You're trying to use `n`... to define `n`. You can't, because `n` doesn't exist yet until that line runs.

I believe what you want instead is:

```
for n in range(0,len(a),1):
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get from 0th to the last index so that my actual code works, if possible can you please correct my actual code and explain a bit on that. TIA